# Calculating the area covered by a polygon feature within a buffer area of a point in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two datasets - one of points from bird nesting data and one of the extent of woodland. I have created 2km buffers around each nesting point and I want to find out what area of woodland there is within each point buffer. Can someone point me in the right direction as to what process I use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform an `intersection` of buffers and woodland.

[image]

[image]

You'll get a new polygon as result, which you can calculate the area(s) of.

*I assume you are talking about the area of woodland? If not you can skip the last step and just find the woodland information in the attribute table of the intersection layer.*

[image]

For this it is necessary to use a metric projection. Then open the attribute table of the intersection result layer and create a new field with field calculator and enter `$area`. The result will be in m².

[image]

Comment: The very first thing I can think about is that your layers are not in the same CRS.

Comment: Yes, m², 27700 is a metric projection.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry one more question - in my output table there appear to be several different values for the same point ID. For example, the same coordinate nest point has two areas of grassland associated with it - 53m and 9727m in different rows of my output CSV. What have I done here?

Comment: Please avoid deleting your comments, in case someone else having the same issue, these might be helpful for others. -- Hard to tell. I assume one nest buffer intersects with more than one woodland area?

Comment: Ah ok, so maybe I need to take the total of all the rows for each point ID? The woodland is quite fragmented..

Comment: You could try `Collect Geometries` tool to merge your woodland areas by type. This will result in one multipart polygon per woodland type. Or alternatively `Dissolve`. Then perform the intersection again.

Comment: they all have different numbers in the ogc_fid column if that helps...

Comment: Is this the only attribute in your woodland layer? But maybe it is better to open up a new question for this.